# Twitter bootstrap modal leaves screen unclickable after it disappears

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use the modal feature of the twitter bootstrap framework with iOS5. 
After the user clicks on the close button, the modal disappears correctly, but no other item of the screen seems to be clickable. This behaviour just occurs under iOS5.

It's working correctly with iOS 6 and in any desktop browser.

Here the close button:

```
<a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
```

May this occur because of the missing html5/css3 support in iOS5?

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem. Thanks for posting this question. I was just struggling with this only 2 days ago.

Comment: Does it work with any other way of dismissing the modal (clicking somewhere outside of the modal, pressing the escape key)? Can you give the whole modal HTML (and JS, possibly)?

Comment: the modal box will also bring up a background overlay which prevents touches outside the background view. i suspect that when the modal box is dismissed, the background overlay is still present. try having a look in to that.

Comment: @Liam I already tried this. I found a workaround by removing all the related html by hand. the modal itself, the background overlay and some CSS class which was assigned to the body tag (something like 'modal-open'). I'm still not sure what's wrong, because it works 100% perfect with iOS6

Comment: Could you provide a working test-case on jSFiddle?

Comment: Are you running the latest bootstrap version (2.3.1)? Seems to be working fine with iOS 5.1.1 in [the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).The latest patch fixed an issue with the backdrop removal when no backdrop was set. Check the [release notes](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/03/01/bootstrap-2-3-1-released/)

Comment: I'm running bootstrap 2.2.2 and jquery 1.8.3 under iOS 5.1.1 and it works great here.

Comment: just to point out that <a type="button" ...> is not valid, you should use <a class="btn close"...> or <button type="button" ...>

Answer (score 2):

mr Liam say true: the modal box will also bring up a background overlay which prevents touches outside the background view.
Yor may catch it in debug and write your own js to close it when button clicked.
Like $('.your_class').hide()

Also take attention that this problem may occurred when you open modal window and leave the page. If you click 'back' on device, you may see same problem

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old topic, but I thought I would post the solution anyways as this is still a problem with bootstrap v. 3.2.0. It is only an iOS 5.0.0 to 5.1.1 problem.

The problem is to do with the buggy implementation of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` on iOS 5.

I simply added an `ios5` class through JavaScript to `html` (by user agent detection, though not the best approach either). Then you can use the following and it will fix the problem.

```
.ios5 .modal {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
```